# Why is this C# Class Library project unable to create a COM compatible DLL?

Tags: c#, dll, com, class-library, typelib

I've downloaded a C# Class Library called [TreeViewAdv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/treeviewadv/), that I need to use in another project as a COM DLL.

It builds successfully (Release, not Debug).

- Registering the built DLL using "regasm" says **"Types registered successfully"**
- Registering with "gacutil" says **"Assembly successfully added to cache"**

In the C# project settings:

- Application > Assembly Information > **Make assembly COM-Visible** is checked
- Build > **Register for COM Interop** is checked

When I attempt to add this built DLL to the VS via the "Choose Toolbox Items" dialog though, it says "Self-registration for XYZ.tlb failed."

Anything else I have to configure? Why can't I use this DLL in VS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to forget [this post](http://www.vbforums.com/showpost.php?p=1739845&postcount=4) that steps you thru registering the class.

Comment: @Jeremy,

I also have the need to use TreeViewAdv as a COM component.  Did you succeed in getting it to work in that manner?  If so, do you have any pointers for me, or better yet, a COM-enabled DLL you could pass along?